# Qt Widgets scaling for multiple platforms and languages

Tags: qt

I have a Qt project localized to two languages. Moreover it has to work on 3 platforms: Windows, Mac and Linux. I have some issues with scaling of text: one language may be longer that another and Linux native look (Fusion) is 'wider' too. Unfortunately, I can't even check how it looks on Mac (I have to ask other people to compile this project and prepare release).

I'm afraid that I have to switch style of this project to Fusion because it looks the same on all platforms: than I'll have to handle only localization scaling (If I set the same font and its size for all platforms too). Are there other solutions how to handle scaling of text and widgets for 3 platforms and 2 languages?

In case of switching to Fusion, I can set Fusion as default style for preview (STRL+SHIFT+R in Qt Creator) but I do not know how to set Fusion as default style for designer? Is there a way to do it?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: if you want to force you to use that style you must do it by means of code with `a.setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: in _Designer_ do you mean going to _Form_ , _Preview in_ and selecting _Fusion Style_ ?

Comment: I can change theme to Fusion as well as font to Arial. Also I can preview 'Forms' as Fusion. The problem is that in designer I see everything as earlier (Windows style).